# How to open a LWC component on stage change in Opportunity?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

We have a requirement to open a pop up window with all the details when an existing Opportunity is closed. For this I created a LWC component and added to Opportunity Record page, if I use LastModifiedDate instead of StageName it is opening a pop-up window. But for stage changes it is not even calling the component. Can anyone please suggest if I have to make any changes?

**LWC:**

*oppComponent.html*

```
<template>
    <template if:true={isShowModal}>
        <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <!-- modal header start -->
                <header class="slds-modal__header">
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" title="Close" onclick={hideModalBox}>
                        <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close" alternative-text="close" variant="inverse" size="small"></lightning-icon>
                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
                    </button>
                    <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Coming Soon</h2>
                </header>

                <!-- modal body start -->
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                    <p>Add Logic</p>
                </div>

                <!-- modal footer start-->
                <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" onclick={hideModalBox}>Cancel</button>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
    </template>
</template>
```

*oppComponent.js*

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire ,track} from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
const FIELDS=['Opportunity.Id','Opportunity.StageName'];
export default class FutureOpportunity extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    opportunity;
    lastModifiedDate;
    StageName;
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })
    wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
        if (error) {
           console.log('error occured'+error);
        } else if (data) {
            this.opportunity = data;
            let sname = this.opportunity.StageName;
            if(!this.StageName) {
                this.StageName = this.opportunity.StageName;
            }
            if (sname !== this.StageName) {
                this.showNotification();
                this.showModalBox();
            }
        }
    }
    showNotification() {
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Success',
            message: 'Opportunity Updated',
            variant: 'success'
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
    @track isShowModal = false;
    showModalBox() {
        this.isShowModal = true;
    }
    hideModalBox() {
        this.isShowModal = false;
    }
}
```

*oppComponent.js-meta.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>56.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
<target>lightning__HomePage</target>
<target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
<target>lightning__AppPage</target>
<target>lightning__Tab</target>
    </targets>

</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [publishing a Platform Event from flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_publish_flow.htm) when doing your changes to the Opportunity object and [then listen(subscribe) to this event in your LWC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_subscribe_lc.htm) and render it immediately.

Comment: thanks for your reply, we don't want to use flow as there are lot of issues going on in our org with flows. Is it possible if we use LWC inside aura?

Comment: you can send the platform event form other sources, like apex trigger or something. sorry, don't understand what's the point with aura component?